# knitr example doesn't produce graphics

Tags: graphics, r, knitr

I tried compiling the [given MWE](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/inst/examples/knitr-minimal.Rnw) for testing knitr:

```
%% LyX 2.1.3 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=2,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}
\hypersetup{
 pdfstartview={XYZ null null 1}}
\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}
<<setup, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE>>=
library(knitr)
# set global chunk options
opts_chunk$set(fig.path='figure/minimal-', fig.align='center', fig.show='hold')
options(formatR.arrow=TRUE,width=90)
@


\title{A Minimal Demo of knitr}


\author{Yihui Xie}

\maketitle
You can test if \textbf{knitr} works with this minimal demo. OK, let's
get started with some boring random numbers:

<<boring-random>>=
set.seed(1121)
(x=rnorm(20))
mean(x);var(x)
@

The first element of \texttt{x} is \Sexpr{x[1]}. Boring boxplots
and histograms recorded by the PDF device:

<<boring-plots, fig.width=4, fig.height=4, out.width='.4\\linewidth'>>=
## two plots side by side (option fig.show='hold')
par(mar=c(4,4,.1,.1),cex.lab=.95,cex.axis=.9,mgp=c(2,.7,0),tcl=-.3,las=1)
boxplot(x)
hist(x,main='')
@

Do the above chunks work? You should be able to compile the \TeX{}
document and get a PDF file like this one: \url{https://github.com/yihui/knitr/releases/download/doc/knitr-minimal.pdf}.
The Rnw source of this document is at \url{https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/inst/examples/knitr-minimal.Rnw}.
\end{document}
```

I copied the code into a Sweave document in RStudio and clicked "Compile PDF." The resulting PDF looks kind of like this (2 pages placed side-by-side):

[image: both pages]

What's wrong?

Comment: This is the hazard of using a template without reading the supporting manuals.  The code  `knitr-minimal.Rnw` is written in `knitr` complaint syntax and it preprocesses-compiles-views correctly using the knit-command then pdflatex then view-pdf.  However, you added line 18,   `\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}` which is a Sweave specific command requiring the Sweave preprocessor.  The end result is not the expected output.   Remove line 18.

Comment: You have to compile it with knitr and not with Sweave. With Sweave I get your result and with knitr (if you omit the line with sweaveopts), you should obtain the desired result

Answer (score 1):

RStudio by default uses Sweave for .Rnw files and adds the line `\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}` after `\begin{document}`. [Set "Sweave" from Global or Project Options (from the Tool menu) to specify knitr processing instead of Sweave.](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200532247)

Comment: Go here and see how to change the RStudio default. http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/rstudio/.  Or, you will have to do a bit of rewriting as Sweave does not handle graphics as cleanly as knitr.  In Sweave, to get two graphics side by side you have to set up a dual pane graphic window in R and manage all the labels, etc in R.  Knitr allows you to take more advantage of the control of structure offered by LaTeX.